# How would one expose secure access to a node.js server running on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js

Imagine I have a Rails application, and I'd like authenticated users to have access to the services of another application ( written in node.js ). How can I make sure only users authenticated ( logged in ) into my Rails application can access the node one?

EDIT: both applications are running on Heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to implement SSO using tokens. There's some info here by ideascale.com

http://support.ideascale.com/kb/ideascale-setup/single-sign-on-multipass-token-based-cookie-based